# C - I want to reverse a Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to reverse a linked list and my code doesn't seem to work. I don't know what is wrong with it. I used a `reverse()` function I found here, I even tested it on paper so I'm pretty sure the code is good but I must be missing something still. I'd love to find out what is wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct node{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
}node;

void push(int val, node **head){
    node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* current=*head;
    temp->val=val;
    if(*head==NULL)
        {*head=temp;
        temp->next=NULL;}
    else
        {while(current->next!=NULL)
            current=current->next;
    current->next=temp;
    temp->next=NULL;}
 }
int reverse(node * head){
   node *previous = NULL;
   node *current = head;
   node *forward;
   while (current != NULL) {
       forward = current->next;
       current->next = previous;
       previous = current;
       current = forward;
      }
    return previous;

   }
 void print(node *new_head){

    node* current2=new_head;
    current2=current2->next;
    while(current2!=NULL)
     {
       printf("%d", current2->val);
       current2=current2->next;
      }}

int main()
{   node * head= NULL;
    int n;
    node * new_head;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    push(n,head);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    push(n,head);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    push(n,head);
    new_head=reverse(head);
    print(new_head);

    return 0;}
```

I just want to reverse an input like: 1,2,3. So the output would be 3,2,1.

Comment: Does it compile? What do the error messages say?

Comment: Do you need bi-directional linked list?

Comment: `previous` is not an `int`.

Comment: @wildplasser it does http://ideone.com/UzUnPT

Comment: it compiles, no errors given. but it stopps working.

Comment: Your push is strange. I would expect push to add node before the current head, not at the end of the list (it would be also much cheaper, performance-wise).

Comment: @Ashalynd I just barely started understanding linked lists and I know most of what I wrote is pretty weird/inneficient.

Comment: `void push(int val, node **head){` push() expects a pointer to pointer as 2nd argument. `node * head= NULL; push(n,head);` but you are giving it a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
} node;

void push( node **head, int val )
{
    node **current = head;

    while ( *current ) current = &( *current )->next;

    *current = ( node * )malloc( sizeof( node ) );

    ( *current )->val  = val;
    ( *current )->next = NULL;
}

node * reverse( node * head )
{
    node *new_head = NULL;
    node *current = head;

    while ( current ) 
    {
        node *next = current->next;
        current->next = new_head;
        new_head = current;
        current = next;
    }

    return new_head;
}

void print( const node *head )
{
    for ( ; head; head = head->next ) printf( "%d ", head->val );
    printf( "\n" );
}

void delete( node *head )
{
    while ( head )
    {
        node *tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free( tmp );
    }
}

int main()
{   
    node *head = NULL;
    int n;

    scanf( "%d", &n );
    push( &head, n );

    scanf( "%d", &n );
    push( &head, n );

    scanf( "%d", &n );
    push( &head, n );

    print( head );

    head = reverse( head );

    print( head );

    delete( head );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter 1 2 3 the output will be

```
1 2 3 
3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your reverse is working. It's the `push` method that doesn't work according to spec: it moves the new element to the end of your list, instead of before the current head. So you already have the reversed list before the call to your `reverse` method (which promptly reverses it the other way round).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
}node;

void push(int val, node **head){
    node* temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* current=*head;

    temp->val=val;
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(*head==NULL){
        *head=temp;
    } else {
        while(current->next!=NULL)
            current=current->next;
        current->next=temp;
    }
}
node *reverse(node * head){
    node *rev = NULL;
    node *current = head;
    node *temp;

    while (current != NULL) {
        temp = current->next;
        current->next =rev;
        rev = current;
        current = temp;
    }
    return rev;
}
void print(node *new_head){
    node* current2=new_head;
    while(current2!=NULL){
        printf("%d ", current2->val);
        current2=current2->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    int n;
    node * head= NULL;
    node * new_head;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    push(n, &head);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    push(n, &head);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    push(n, &head);
    //print(head);
    new_head=reverse(head);
    print(new_head);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`push( n, &head);` is what you have to do in order to pass `head` pointer by pointer. Otherwise in `push` method `node* current=*head;` will result in segmentation fault as you are passing null pointer itself instead of pointer to it.